# Palindrome Checker Assistance

Tags: python, palindrome

I need help with my Palindrome Checker using the provided instructions :(

If someone could show and explain the missing code, it would be a big help!

[Palindrome Checker](https://www.online-python.com/OWoKCYMFfj)

Comment: First clean up the string (remove spaces, make it all lowercase) then compare the result with its letters in reversed order.  You can reverse a string using `myString[::-1] `

Comment: Please read the descriptions of the tags you are adding before adding them (note the description of the `basic` tag).

Comment: Do you also have a question or do you just want to show us your code?

Comment: My apologies for the hostility you have been experiencing. In most cases, it is helpful to include a clear title (what you have is excellent), a clear description of what we can assist you with along with other information such as what you have tried, and a snippet of code that you are working on (the original code was excellent).

Comment: When you have made a reasonable effort to resolve your issue, we are generally more eager to assist. This helps in preventing us from answering homework questions all day long.

Comment: Don't hide the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's say you have a list:
`list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`

You can use
`list1.append(7)`
to output
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`

And you can use
`list1.insert(0, 0)`
to output
`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

Feel free to cleanup this code:

```
def is_palindrome(input_string):
    '''Take a string as input and return True if it is a palindrome 
       and False otherwise.'''

    # We'll create two lists to hold the string in forward 
    # and backward order to compare them later.
    forward = []
    backward = []

    # Traverse through each letter of the input string
    for letter in input_string:
        if letter != ' ':
            forward.append(letter)
            backward.insert(0, letter)

    print(forward.__str__())
    print(backward.__str__())

    str1 = ''.join(str(e) for e in forward)
    str2 = ''.join(str(e) for e in backward)
    print(str1)
    print(str2)
    if str1 == str2:
        return True
    return False
# Add any non-blank letters to the
# end of one list and to the front
# of the other list.
# Add your loop code block below this line.


# Compare the strings and return True
# or False accordingly.
# Hint: there are several ways to achieve this.
# Think about how to go from a list to a string.
# Be sure to ignore differences in upper and lower case.
# Add you code below this line.


def main():
    # Prompt user for a string to check

    print("Welcome to the Palindrome Checker Program!")
    input_str = input("Enter a string to check: ")

    # Invoke the is_palindrome function and print the result based on the return value
    # Add code below this line.
    if is_palindrome(input_str):
        print("Is Palindrome")
    else:
        print("Is not palindrome")



main()
```